# How to hide content from File2HD?

Tags: html, .htaccess, security

There is a website called file2hd.com which can download any type of content from your website including audio, movies, links, applications, objects and style sheets. Of course this doesn't work for high profile websites such as Google, but is there there a type of method I can use to cloak content on my website and prevent this?

E.g. Using a HTML Code, or using .htaccess method?

Answers are appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you hide something from the software, you also hide it from regular users. Unless you have a password-protected part of your website. But even then, those users with passwords will be able to fetch all loaded content - HTML is transparent. And since you didn't provide what kind of content are you trying to hide, it's hard to give you a more accurate answer.

One thing you can do, but it works just for certain file types, is to server just small portions of a file. For example, you have a video on your page and you're fetching 5-second bits of the video from the server every 5 seconds. That way, in order for someone to download the whole thing, they'd have to get all the bits (by watching the whole thing) and then find a way to join the parts... and it's usually just not worth it. Think of Google Maps... and Google uses this/similar technique on a few other products as well.